# Where can I develop 110 film?

Tags: film, image-processing, developing, 110

Where can I develop 110 film from my Pentax 110 SLR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took mine (also from a Pentax Auto110!) to the local fancy camera store, and they couldn't do it. But CVS could! They sent it in to Kodak for processing, so it took a little while, but the results came back just fine.

Comment: When Was this? How much does it cost?

Comment: Hmmm; about a year ago. I haven't heard that they'd stopped, but it's possible they have. It wasn't expensive at all.

Answer (score 3):

I found two websites online that do mail-order development for 110 film:

- [Bison Photo](http://www.bisonphoto.com/Film_Developing.html)
- [Dwayne's Photo](http://www.dwaynesphoto.com/newsite2006/color-neg-processprint.html)

You may also have luck getting it developed any place that still sells 110 film - I read that some WalMart Photos have the ability to develop 110 film.